# Formatting dates on excel 2010

Tags: excel, csv

Does anyone know how to convert this string 20.01.2012 09:30:11 to excel date 01/20/2012 09:30:11. Tried to use the "text to column" tool, it is successful if the string does not contain the time (hh:mm:ss) part. Anybody can help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the cells in question and do a find and replace...

Find .
Replace /

I tested it and it worked perfectly :)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Not sure it'll always work: the above date has days first, followed by months - while the required format has months first! Therefore, please check if 01.02.2012 is converted to 01/02 (wrong) or 02/01 (correct)!

Answer (score 0):

**Formal way**

You can convert it in with the following formula:

```
=DATE(MID(A1,7,4),MID(A1,4,2),LEFT(A1,2))+TIME(MID(A1,13,2),MID(A1,16,2),RIGHT(A1,2))
```

This formula extracts all bits (days, months, etc.) and constructs a date and a time out of it.

**Manual way**

If you temporarilly change the date format in the Regional settings of Windows to the format you want to import (in this case German), Excel will understand it as a proper date:

1. Change date format
2. Open Excel and paste your dates
3. Save and close Excel
4. Change date format back
5. Reopen Excel file